# Dictionary prefixed to requests get() method in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, session, get, python-requests

I am currently looking at some code for a finance API and there is an example function which seems to action a specified type of request (I'm very new to requests, so still learning about this).
I don't understand the syntax in the functions return..  I have never seen a dictionary prepended to a method like this, what is happening here?  Thanks for the advice.

```
import requests 

def dispatch_request(http_method):
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers.update({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        'X-MBX-APIKEY': KEY
    })
    return {
        'GET': session.get,
        'DELETE': session.delete,
        'PUT': session.put,
        'POST': session.post,
    }.get(http_method, 'GET')
```

Should anybody be interested the example in full can be seen here: https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-signature-examples/blob/master/python/spot.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're basically using the dictionary as a "`switch` expression"; if you're familiar with `switch`es in other languages like C and [Java](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/325) (although `switch`es in C are statements, and don't evaluate to a value).

If `http_method` was `'POST'` for example:

```
{   'GET': session.get,
    'DELETE': session.delete,
    'PUT': session.put,
    'POST': session.post,
}.get('POST')
```

The call to `get` would evaluate to `session.post`, then that would be returned. It's simply a way to replace some `if`s to decide what to return.

Comment: That's great, without knowing the terminology I was struggling to search an answer.  
This particular function is supposed to be used in GET, DELETE, PUT and POST scenarios, so any idea why have they have hardcoded the 'GET' as a second parameter in the method?   .get(http_method, 'GET')

Comment: @Dude The second parameter of `get` is the default to return if the supplied key (`http_method`) isn't in the dictionary. They're using it to default to `GET` if the caller supplies invalid data (an invalid HTTP method). This is arguably a bad thing to do though since it covers up bugs. If you ran `dispatch_request("PUST")` accidentally, it would do a `GET` request instead of raising an error.

Comment: @Carcigenicate.  Agreed.  The earlier that errors are found, the better.  Bad input should cause an exception, not quietly guess what the user intended.

Comment: @FrankYellin Yep. I've always been a believer in "let it crash". If the caller needs to handle it, let them do so. That's better than assuming what they want.

Comment: thanks, I had been confused here by the use of .get as a method of switching, as opposed to requests.get()

Comment: @Dude Ya, those `get` methods are completely different. Their names are an unfortunate coincidence here.